# Ninject: property injection into ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I want to implement DI inside ActionFilterAttribute by Ninject. I've found [this manual](http://damienbod.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/) (actually I've read tens of them today) but it's for Unity. My attempt to implement it on Ninject is here:

```
public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IDepend Depend { get; set; }
    // another code
}
```

bindings:

```
public class NinjectResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    // another code
    private IKernel AddRequestBindings(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // another code
        kernel.Bind<IDepend>().To<Depend>();
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

custom FilterProvider:

```
public class WebApiNinjectActionFilterProvider : ActionDescriptorFilterProvider, IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IFilterProvider> _filterProviders;

    public WebApiNinjectActionFilterProvider(IKernel kernel, IEnumerable<IFilterProvider> filterProviders)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
        _filterProviders = filterProviders;
    }

    public new IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = _filterProviders.SelectMany(fp => fp.GetFilters(configuration, actionDescriptor)).ToList();
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            // GET ActivationException HERE!!!!!
            _kernel.Inject(filter.Instance);
        }
        return filters;
    }

    public static void RegisterFilterProviders(IKernel ninjectKernel)
    {
        var providers = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders().ToList();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider),
                                                       new WebApiNinjectActionFilterProvider(ninjectKernel, providers));
        var defaultprovider = providers.First(i => i is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Remove(typeof(IFilterProvider), defaultprovider);
    }
}
```

is called from WebApiConfig:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(ninjectKernel);

        WebApiNinjectActionFilterProvider.RegisterFilterProviders(ninjectKernel);
    }
```

and finally action:

```
    [MyFilter]
    public async Task<string> Test()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
```

The problem is I get an ActivationException in this line:

```
_kernel.Inject(filter.Instance);
```

ActivationException's Activation path:

2) Injection of dependency IDepend into property Depend of type MyFilter

1) Request for MyFilter

If to inject same property to controller - it injects fine. Any ideas how to improve my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing IActionFilter DI in wrong way. The right way I've found in [this blogpost of Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/).

DI via Ninject was implemented this way:

```
var myFilter = new MyFilter(ninjectKernel.Get<IDepend>());
config.Filters.Add(myFilter);
```